# Can a billboard be placed everywhere?

Tags: little-big-workshop

Billboards should distribute jobs to multiple workstation of the same type. I now place all my billboards in the same room as those workstations, but sometimes they take up precious space. Is it possible to place billboards somewhere else (for example, a distant 'billboardroom')? I never caught an employee looking at the billboard. Will the machine input zones work well with this solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just tried it. Made a separate room on the far outskirts of my factory, but with all the right connections (loading zones and machinery). I saw nobody walking towards the billboards, and introduce unnecessary walking time, and the billboards seem to do their job anyway. This means that **it works** , in the way I described in the question.